# Atom shortcut for end of line (Windows)

Tags: windows, atom-editor

What is the native atom editor shortcut for quickly navigating to the end of beginning of a line in Windows? Can't seem to find it anywhere!

Comment: `home` and `end`? Or create a custom shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find here alot of shortcuts for windows, mac and linux

https://github.com/nwinkler/atom-keyboard-shortcuts

By default the home key and the end key move the cursor to the beginning of the line and to the end of the line respectly